# Can't add a *.so library in Android Studio. JniLibs directory don't work

Tags: android, android-studio, .so, pcsc

I researched a lot for an answer of my question, but I didn't find anything.
I can't add the .so library in my project.

I put the library in /app/src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a. The project will complile but on execution the following error comes.

Thank you for all answers.

[Structure of directorys is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nsu0m.jpg).
arms64-v8a is the correct folder for my System.

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.vtas_kassenterminal"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'org/apache/http/version.properties'
        exclude 'org/apache/http/nio/version.properties'
        exclude 'org/apache/http/client/version.properties'
        exclude 'org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultHttpServerIODispatch'
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/acssmc-1.1.4.jar')
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
}
```

Log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.vtas_kassenterminal, PID: 10504
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.vtas_kassenterminal-zh4y12ECK4PCd-N-FXMp6A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.vtas_kassenterminal-zh4y12ECK4PCd-N-FXMp6A==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libpcsclite.so"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1011)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1657)
        at com.example.vtas_kassenterminal.JacspcscLoader.<clinit>(JacspcscLoader.java:280)
        at com.example.vtas_kassenterminal.nfcTest.onCreate(nfcTest.java:135)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7258)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7249)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1222)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1724)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means **libpcsclite.so** not find in **arms64-v8a** folde. Try to remove your .so file extra character **.1.0.0** (I saw this in image)

If above solution not work follow the below.

The .so file not only work in **arms64-v8a** folder. Add your .so file in **armeabi-v7a** directory. The folder name depend on Phone Hardware (May be processor).

And .so file May be different for specific folder like **arms64-v8a** or **armeabi-v7a** and so on. Generally maximum device cover **armeabi-v7a**.

Comment: Thank you I came a step forward, but now it says:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libdl.so.2" not found
but I don't want to add this library. 
I only say:
static {
     System.loadLibrary("pcsclite");
    }

Comment: Are you sure that libpcsclite has no dependency on libdl.so? .so file contains some method or function and it may be depend on other .so file

Comment: Where I should add the libdl.so? Also in arms64-v8a directory?

Comment: All .so file will be in the same directory. **Note:** single .so file has several directory type. that i mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Welcome :) I think you got basic idea.

Answer (score 2):

you should have to write above code so that gradle can able to find out ".so" files on your project's jniLibs Folder.

```
android {
sourceSets {
       main {         
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jnilibs']          
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: `src/main/jniLibs` is the default search location, see https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds#jniLibs